# About flashing boot image of Android

Tags: android, kernel

I am not familiar with a Android kernel compile process.
But I encountered a problem recently, and it troubled me so much.

Here is the problem descrition:
Based on Android, I build customed images including boot.img, system.img and so on.
Then I need to flash those images to physical device in order to boot to Android Home Screen.
Before compiling those images files, I have set a new kernel command line:

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE="root=/dev/mtdblock2 rw init=/init console=ttyS0, 115200 mem=128M uard_dma android"
```

After compiling those images, I opened boot.img in vim and saw the following string in it:

```
"root=/dev/mtdblock2 rw init=/init console=ttyS0, 115200 mem=128M uard_dma android"
```

But when I flashed the boot.img into device, I got the different output like this:

```
**Kernel command line: console=ttyO2,115200n8 earlyprintk**
```

In other word, I set the kernel command line value, and it was wrote into boot.img, but when
flash boot.img into device, I got a different kernel command line value.

Has anybody ever encountered this problem and got it fixed?
Really appreciating your help.
Thanks advanced!

Answer (score 1):

The bootloader will be passing a command line to the kernel.
For example if **u-boot** bootloader is used,
it will be contained in the u-boot variable **bootargs**

This can be verified at the bootloader prompt.
For example if the device is using u-boot bootloader.

1. Connect the device to your PC over a serial prompt.
2. Launch a serial emulator on your PC (minicom, teraterm, hyper-terminal).
3. Power-on the device.
4. Press any key to halt the device boot at the bootloader stage itself.
5. Now on the u-boot prompt enter the following command:

   **u-boot#** printenv
6. This will list all the uboot-variables. Note the value of variable **bootargs**.
7. This can be modified by using the following command:

   **u-boot#** setenv bootargs ''
8. To save this value across reboots use the following commmand:

   **u-boot#** saveenv

Similar functionality is available in other bootloaders as well.

Comment: Your meaning is I can modify the bootargs varaible by u-boot bootloader, do I understand you right?

Comment: The curious thing is I already set the place where to boot from, but it cannot find the place when boot the kernel, the log tell me the space I specified is not existing.

My current situation is similiar with this issue:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-porting/oTz-Ak_2nrQ/vypJ3HSCrigJ

Comment: As mentioned in the above link you shared, you need to update in your bootargs (in u-boot), the 'root=<proper-path-to-device>' where your file-system is flashed on the device.

Comment: Do you mean that the place spcified by me is overrided by u-boot? So I need to reset the "root" value?

Comment: yes. Can you try adding "root=/dev/mtdblock2" to bootargs in u-boot and save and boot?...

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems this error is caused by other's miscoding. Appreciate your prompt!